# How to update ArcGIS 10.0 extension for ArcGIS 10.1?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-10.1, extensions

I have an ArcGIS 10.0 extension which will no longer install for users who have upgraded to ArcGIS 10.1. Are there a defined set of changes that need to be made in order to upgrade the extension, or is it dependent on extension options, such as the libraries that are called?

The error recieved upon install is: `"Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the C:\...extensionname.dll assembly. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoadedExceptions property for more information."`

Any other comments/advice on moving extensions to 10.1?

Comment: Is this an add-in or a traditional COM component? What error do you receive?

Comment: It is a traditional COM component. The error is "Error 1001. Unable to get installer types in the C:\...extensionname.dll assembly. --> Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the LoadedExceptions property for more information."

Comment: Try using [fuslogvw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) to view the assembly binding logs. Read here for more: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you will need to install VS2010, perform a project upgrade, and set any referenced ESRI assemblies' Specific Version property to false. See here for more info: [Migrating ArcGIS 9.3.x and 10 Desktop and Engine custom components to ArcGIS 10.1](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/conceptualhelp/#/Migrating_ArcGIS_9_3_x_and_10_Desktop_and_Engine_custom_components_to_ArcGIS_10_1/0001000002m2000000/)

Comment: This documentation is exactly what I was looking for. Many thanks.